# Get Process StartTime from a remote server using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm using following command to get the start time of a windows process. This is to get the running time of a process to terminate if it running too long.

`$ProcessStartTime =(Get-Process $WinProcess -computer $computer).StartTime` (Not working)

above code not returning Start Time value from a remote server ( it can access other process information). But it getting values for a local process with following command.

`$ProcessStartTime =(Get-Process $WinProcess).StartTime` (Working)

Can some one help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use wmi for this job:

```
gwmi win32_process -computername $computer| 
? { $_.name -eq "powershell.exe" } | 
% { $_.ConvertToDateTime( $_.CreationDate )}
```

Comment: Are you sure you have used `myprocess.exe` (name and extension) in the where-object scriptblock filter?

Comment: Yes. It worked after that. thanks (took some time to find that).

Answer (score 0):

i've the same result as you, but you can create a new session on the remote computer then use invoke-command to run your script :

```
$sess=new-pssession $computer
$ProcessStartTime =invoke-command -session $sess -ScriptBlock{ (Get-Process $WinProcess).StartTime}
```